# TypeScript: I can't get the Float/Decimal Math working correctly. (82.80000000000001, but should be 82.8)

Tags: javascript, typescript, floating-point, decimal

**Issue:**

I'm having an issue with the decimal/floating point math in JavaScript/Typescript. [I'm aware of posts about these issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), but I'm having no luck.

**Desired Result:**

`82.8`

**Result:**

`82.80000000000001`

**What's Working:**

`total += (array[i] * weight[i] * 100) / 100;` line is correctly working, but that same logic isn't working with the `total`.

**What I've Tried:**

1. In another function, I've multiplied and divided the value by 10 or 100. This works, but I can't get it to work in my case.

```
const remainder: number = ((1 - Math.sqrt(value)) * 10) / 10;
```

2. People have suggested using `toFixed(2);`, but that changes the typecast of the number to a string, which is what I don't want.

**calulateWeightedAverage.tsx:**

```
// Calculate Weighted Average
export const calculateAverageWeighted = (array: Array<number>, weight: Array<number>) => {
  // Check If Data Exists
  if (array.length >= 1) {
    // Weight Length: Must Equal Array Length
    if (weight.length == array.length) {
      // Weight Sum: Must Equal 1 Or 100
      if (weight.reduce((total: number, value: number) => { return total + value }) === 1 || weight.reduce((total: number, value: number) => { return total + value }) === 100) {
        // Total
        let total: number = 0;

        // Iterate Over Array
        let i: number = 0;
        while (i < array.length) {
          // Add To Total
          total += (array[i] * weight[i] * 100) / 100;

          // Increase I
          i++;
        }

        // IMPORTANT: FLOAT MATH (NOT WORKING HERE)
        return (total * 100) / 100;
      }
      else {
        // Error
        throw new Error('Error: Values of Weight Array must be equal to 1 or 100 (calculateAverageWeighted)');
      }
    }
    // Array Length Is Less Than Weight Length
    else if (array.length < weight.length || array.length > weight.length) {
      // Error
      throw new Error('Error: Length of weight must be equal to input Array (calculateAverageWeighted)');
    }
  }
  else {
    // Error
    throw new Error('Error: Empty Array (calculateAverageWeighted)');
  }
};
```

Comment: Just turn it into a number after using `toFixed`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) You say that you read it, but that is still fundamentally the reason you can't. `82.8` is simply not exactly representable in a number in JavaScript.

Comment: If that math works for one number, but not another then compare the *values*. For *some* values it will "work" (or appear to) and for others it won't.

Comment: So far, it looks like the best route is to use `return Number((total).toFixed(10));` because 10 still gives enough accuracy, but under the 17 max decimals for JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Typical floating point values are [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), some n-bit integer times a power-of-2 where `n` and exponent range are limited.

Code like `total += (array[i] * weight[i] * 100) / 100;` performs 2 multiplication, a division and an addition.  Each product,quotient and sum are likely not the exactly the same as the mathematical expected one as the result is *rounded* and saved to the closest dyadic rational.

82.8 itself is not *exactly* encode-able.  Instead the closest value is

```
82.7999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875
82.8                                             // OP's hoped for result (not possible)
82.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125  // Next best choice.
82.80000000000001                                // OP's reported result
```

---

Instead, accept that the result is not exactly the same mathematical one and limit reported result to a rounded result, perhaps 14-15 significant digits.

```
// 345678901234    
82.800000000000                                  // 14 significant places
```

Or perform the math using integers: scale everything by 0.001.

Or use decimal floating point. (still 1.0/7.0 is not exact there either)

Or perform using exact based math libraries.

Or accept that 82.80000000000001 is simple *close enough*.